# How to display the content of a particular directory (folder) in HTML?

Tags: html

I've just faced the problem, that I cannot display the content of a directory (folder) of my website (contracted domain). I've got a lot of files uploaded and trying to avoid to do extra work by picking them one by one and set them as link. I remember that I could make it in case of a local directory but now I just can't resolve this issue. I only want to display the content (files and folders) of a directory of my web site.

Comment: This is a Q/A site, not a forum - no need for the conversational bits.

Comment: This depends on your web server configuration. And maybe this question is better suited for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I agree with @divideandconquer.se .. to explain further .. a good practice in servers is to protect its assets and prevent getting index page (folder view) of the host .. what you want is the opposite .. so better check with server experts.

Comment: Thank You for the answers. However, it seems to be easier to make a page containing links. No problem. Thanks again and sorry for bothering, b.r.